# Moving TextView Box made my android app crash

Tags: java, android, crash, textview

I have had this problem crop up a few times and I can't figure out why it should happen. What happened was after moving some stuff around my TextView box ended up on top of an EditText box, which is no good. So I went and moved the TextView box to the bottom of the screen. When I did that, the app would crash when I tried to access the piggybank. However, if I move the TextView box up to the top again, it works fine.. I really don't get it. Anyways, this is the error that I got

```
06-22 09:06:41.928: E/AndroidRuntime(10958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
 start activity ComponentInfo{net.finalexam/net.finalexam.Piggy}: 
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton
```

This is piggy xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/piggy" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtQuarters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of quarters"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDimes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtQuarters"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of dimes"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNickles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDimes"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of nickles"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPennies"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNickles"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of pennies"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDollars"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPennies"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Number of Dollars"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDollars"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Add" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radSubtract"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtract" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Calculate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnCalculate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:textSize="40sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Piggy Java file

```
package net.finalexam;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Piggy extends Activity
{
  double quartersValue = .25;
  double dimesValue = .10;
  double nicklesValue = .05;
  double penniesValue = .01;
  double dollarsValue = 1;
  double quartersMoney;
  double dollarsMoney;
  double dimesMoney;
  double nicklesMoney;
  double penniesMoney;
  double totalMoney;
  double newTotalMoney;
  double oldTotalMoney = 0;
  int numberOfQuarters;
  int numberOfDimes;
  int numberOfNickles;
  int numberOfPennies;
  int numberOfDollars;



  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.piggybank);
    final EditText quarters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtQuarters);
    final EditText dimes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDimes);
    final EditText nickles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNickles);
    final EditText pennies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPennies);
    final EditText dollars = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDollars);
    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
    final TextView results = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResults));
    final RadioButton add = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radAdd);
    final RadioButton subtract = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radSubtract);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        if (quarters.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
          numberOfQuarters = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          numberOfQuarters = Integer.parseInt(quarters.getText().toString());
        }

        if (dimes.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
          numberOfDimes = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          numberOfDimes = Integer.parseInt(dimes.getText().toString());
        }

        if (nickles.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
          numberOfNickles = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          numberOfNickles = Integer.parseInt(nickles.getText().toString());
        }

        if (pennies.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
          numberOfPennies = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          numberOfPennies = Integer.parseInt(pennies.getText().toString());
        }

        if (dollars.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
          numberOfDollars = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          numberOfDollars = Integer.parseInt(dollars.getText().toString());
        }
        quartersMoney = numberOfQuarters * quartersValue;
        dimesMoney = numberOfDimes * dimesValue;
        nicklesMoney = numberOfNickles * nicklesValue;
        penniesMoney = numberOfPennies * penniesValue;
        dollarsMoney = numberOfDollars;
        totalMoney = quartersMoney + dimesMoney + nicklesMoney + penniesMoney + dollarsMoney;
        DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");

        if (add.isChecked())
        {
          if (totalMoney > 0)
          {
            newTotalMoney = oldTotalMoney + totalMoney;
            oldTotalMoney = newTotalMoney;
            results.setText(currency.format(newTotalMoney));
          }
          else
          {
            Toast.makeText(Piggy.this, "You need to do more chores!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
        }
        if (subtract.isChecked())
        {
          newTotalMoney = oldTotalMoney - totalMoney;
        }
        if (newTotalMoney > 0)
        {

          oldTotalMoney = newTotalMoney;
          results.setText(currency.format(newTotalMoney));
        }
        else
        {
          Toast.makeText(Piggy.this, "Save more money kido!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        };
      }
    });
  }

}
```

I have searched for an answer but they all seem to be slightly different situations. Any ideas? Thanks. And like I said, this works fine if the TextView box is overlapping the quarters EditText box.

Edit 1  Here is the screen before the piggy bank

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_launcher_money"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="2px"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_money"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bankses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/bankses"
        android:textSize="25sp">

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
package net.finalexam;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] banks ={"Piggy Bank","Adult Bank"};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main, R.id.bankses, banks));
    }
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Piggy.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Adultbank.class));
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: in which line number u are getting error?

Comment: I'm running the code you've pasted right now and it works just fine. 5 `EditText`, two `RadioButton`, one `Button` and one `TextView`. How do you make it crash?

Comment: well I do feel a bit silly, but there is a list in the acivity before. That I click on. I know there should be no error but for some reason, moving the TextBox causes it to crash. let me get the screen before posted up.

Comment: Same mate, even with that extra `Activity` it doesn't crash. Have you tried cleaning your project on Eclipse? What version of Android are you testing it on?

Comment: OMG... I sometimes think my textbook was made by noobs or something. They never once mentioned this cleaning thing. (which fixed it) lol. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've added an answer to your question. If you can please mark it as accepted I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning your project on Eclipse. It often fixes that kind of problems.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks man. I am really enjoying this programming, just wish some of these types of things were more emphasized. Thanks man.